# Redirect file access

Tags: c++, c, linux, filesystem-access

Is there a way to monitor and redirect file access of a thread or process?

For example a thread wants to read /etc/mysql/my.cnf and I want to change the access to ~/my.cnf or if I run `touch /etc/test.config` I want the file to be redirected to `~/somefolder/etc/test.config`.

I am looking for a libary preferably for C,  C++ which works for Linux/Unix.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming the file handle is accessible from both threads, you could close the old handle, open a new handle and use `dup2()`

Comment: `ln -s /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/my.cnf`?

Comment: The problem is that I want to income other programs and do not know what they will access. Furthermore it is crucial that they do not get any information from they file they originally requested. It should be something like a sandbox.

Comment: Try `chroot`  http://linux.die.net/man/2/chroot

Comment: Thank you seems like what I was looking for, but is there a way to catch all the file accesses which went wrong? Because otherwise I would have to mirror somehow my whole file system to watch the file access.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking an XY question. What is the ACTUAL problem you are trying to solve? You want to divert a SQL server to use a different database?

Comment: I want to write a program which allows me to invoke other programs and process, which are then executed in some sort of sandbox where their file access is redirect to location I have set.

Comment: Would a virtual machine not be a better place to do that sort of thing. What is your overall goal? Subverting something, checking what happens with bad data, testing something?

Comment: My motivation is exactly to avoid the overhead of a VM while keeping the invoked programs sandboxed. The use case is behavior watching like in a Virus Scanner and being able to install libraries without them polluting the underlying operating system (like pythons virtualenvironments).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a shared object that gets pre-loaded when your program starts running. In the .so you'd redefine the libc function `open()`. When the caller (the program that's getting fooled) passes as argument the string `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, you'd instead open `~/my.cnf` and return the opened file descriptor. The caller wouldn't know the difference.

Your shared object would of course need to call the "real" `open()` to to open the file handle; you can get a pointer to the original libc function using `dlsym()`.

This seems overly complicated, but in fact it isn't, it works like a charm. I've used it on several occasions where I had to fool a program that I didn't have the sources for; and it simply works like a clockwork.

If you want to see a proof of concept, check out [my blog](http://kubat.nl/pages/blogaria/310) where I wrote it up. Happy coding!

Comment: I will check this out, but in deed it seams like overly complicated.

Comment: I should add that this works on all levels. For example, if you pre-load your standard Bash with this shared object, then all programs will inherit your redirection. So whether you do "cat /etc/my.cnf", or "vi /etc/my.cnf", or whether you start some other program that accesses /etc/my.cnf: all will be redirected to whatever file you have in mind.

Comment: Okay I will have deeper look at it so I can review your answer.

Comment: Blog link now requires a login, which is too bad because this looks interesting

Answer (score 1):

In linux, you can use bind mounts to map directory *or file* to another path, and per-process mount namespaces to do it for specific application.

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153665/per-process-private-file-system-mount-points) question.

**Example 1:** use [proot](http://proot.me/)

```
$ proot -b ~/alternate_hosts:/etc/hosts
# echo '1.2.3.4 google.com' > /etc/hosts
# resolveip google.com
# IP address of google.com is 1.2.3.4
```

**Example 2:** use [unshare(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html)

```
$ unshare -m
# touch foo bar
# mount -o bind foo bar
# echo hello > foo
# cat bar
hello
```

**Example 3:** use [unshare(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html)

See this post: http://glandium.org/blog/?p=217.